# Connect to RDS DB from local using aws-sdk typescript setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

I'm relatively new to aws-cdk and aws infrastructure in general. I've been able to try to connect to my RDS database locally with no success. I was able to have my fargate cluster connect to the database. Here is my typescript aws-cdk code:

```js
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'TestVpc', {
      maxAzs: 2, // Adjust the number of availability zones as needed
    });

    const clusterSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(
      this,
      'ClusterSecurityGroup',
      {
        vpc,
      },
    );
    clusterSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
      ec2.Peer.ipv4(`${myIp}/32`),
      ec2.Port.allTraffic(), // Replace with the desired port or specific port(s)
      'Allow inbound access from specific IP',
    );

    const database = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'TestDatabase', {
      databaseName: 'myrnamethod',
      engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.POSTGRES,
      publiclyAccessible: true, // Allow public access
      credentials: rds.Credentials.fromPassword(
        process.env.DB_USERNAME as string,
        cdk.SecretValue.unsafePlainText(process.env.DB_PASSWORD as string),
      ),
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
        ec2.InstanceClass.T4G,
        ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO,
      ),
      vpc,
      securityGroups: [clusterSecurityGroup],
    });

    const loadBalancedFargateService =
      new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
        this,
        'TestService',
        {
          memoryLimitMiB: 512,
          cpu: 256,
          taskImageOptions: {
            image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('../', {
              file: 'Dockerfile',
            }),
            containerPort: 3000,
          },
          vpc,
          securityGroups: [clusterSecurityGroup],
        },
      );
    database.connections.allowFrom(
      ec2.Peer.ipv4(`${myIp}/32`),
      ec2.Port.allTraffic(),
      'Allow inbound access from local machine',
    );

    database.connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(
      loadBalancedFargateService.service,
      'Allow inbound access from ECS Fargate service',
    );
    database.connections.allowFrom(
      clusterSecurityGroup,
      ec2.Port.tcp(database.instanceEndpoint.port),
      'Allow inbound access from ECS cluster',
    );
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your DB in a public subnet so that it gets a public IP address. Omit the creation of security groups, let CDK handle that.

```js
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'TestVpc', {
      maxAzs: 2, // Adjust the number of availability zones as needed
    });

    const database = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, 'TestDatabase', {
      databaseName: 'myrnamethod',
      engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.POSTGRES,
      vpcSubnets: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }, // Allow public access
      credentials: rds.Credentials.fromPassword(
        process.env.DB_USERNAME as string,
        cdk.SecretValue.unsafePlainText(process.env.DB_PASSWORD as string),
      ),
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
        ec2.InstanceClass.T4G,
        ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO,
      ),
      vpc,
    });

    const loadBalancedFargateService =
      new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
        this,
        'TestService',
        {
          memoryLimitMiB: 512,
          cpu: 256,
          taskImageOptions: {
            image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('../', {
              file: 'Dockerfile',
            }),
            containerPort: 3000,
          },
          vpc,
        },
      );
    database.connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(
      ec2.Peer.ipv4(`${myIp}/32`),
      'Allow inbound access from local machine',
    );

    database.connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(
      loadBalancedFargateService.service,
      'Allow inbound access from ECS Fargate service',
    );
```

It is also worth noting that you are exposing your password in the cloudformation template in plaintext.

Comment: Noted about the password, I'm just trying to get it up and running first will adjust later. I created a post on reddit and the consensus was you shouldn't put RDS in a public subnet because it can be subject to IP spoofing

Comment: Yes, you shouln't, but you asked how to do this. The proper way is to use a bastion host or session manager, but the answer just answers your quesiont directly.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest and most secure way I could find was to create an EC2 Instance in the same VPC and security group and then within RDS they have an area called `Connected compute resources` and you can connect that EC2 instance.

Then you can SSH into it using a private key (select this option on generation of ec2 instance) and download postgres server/client within the server (or whichever databse) and connect through it. Here's the posgres installation instructions for amazon linux 2023 ec2 instances that I used:

https://devopscube.com/install-configure-postgresql-amazon-linux/

Comment: The question is about CDK